# Subtracting a number of years from a Date

Tags: php, date

Say I have code: `date('Y')."-".date('m')."-".date('d')` How would I go about removing a number of years from the date that piece of code gives me?

Comment: *removing a number of years*? are you talking about subtracting?

Answer (score 9):

```
$date = strtotime('-2 years');
```

And since your printing code is nothing but a convoluted version of this:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', $date);
```

... you could simplify everything into a one-liner:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 years'));
```

Comment: @SilentGhost - Of course you're right. I just took the original code with minimum modifications.

Answer (score 5):

For your situation you could take advantage of PHP's implicit type casting and simply use

```
(date('Y')-42)."-".date('m')."-".date('d')
```

or shorter

```
(date('Y')-42)."-".date('m-d')
```

But, as Álvaro G. Vicario observed in a comment, there is the dreaded 29th of February that doesn't exist in all years so you'll **have to** use [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Example:

```
$someDay = strtotime('2009-11-23');
$threeYearsBefore = strtotime('-3 years', $someDay);
echo date('Y-m-d', $threeYearsBefore);
```

or, relative to the current time,

```
$threeYearsBefore = strtotime('-3 years');
echo date('Y-m-d', $threeYearsBefore);
```

Comment: @SilentGhost - yes, but PHP is weakly typed enough for this to work.

Comment: @DogPooOnYourShoe - just don't try the same trick with months or days! ;-)

Comment: So... `2012-02-29` minus two years equals `2010-02-29`? ;-P

Comment: "just don't try the same trick with months or days!" I second that! The reason it works for years is that they are always the representation of an integer, but months and days may have leading zeroes and PHP converts "04", for example, to the integer 0.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: @Alin: have a look in the calendar.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario :) busted... I'll add it to *known issues*.

Answer (score 4):

As of PHP5.2 you can use the [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class along with [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) to accomplish as well:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$two_years_ago = $now->sub(new DateInterval("P2Y"));
echo $two_years_ago->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: This seems to be the cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-20 years'));